# How can i remove a graphic by id in the graphic layer

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

How can i remove a graphic by id in the graphic layer.I am using esri-javascript-api.Hope any answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you reviewed this documentation? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say the `graphicLayer` is the map graphic's layer, the id attribute is named `"id"` and you want to remove the graphic with the id `0`;

```
var graphicLayer = map.graphics;
var idAttribute = "id";
var idValue = 0;

var toBeRemoved = graphicLayer.graphics.filter(function(graphic) {
  return graphic.attributes[idAttribute] == idValue;
})[0];

graphicLayer.remove(toBeRemoved);
```

You could create a function for doing this in batch

```
function removeGraphicById(graphicLayer, idAttribute, idValue) {
    var toBeRemoved = graphicLayer.graphics.filter(function(graphic) {
      return graphic.attributes[idAttribute] == idValue;
    })[0];

    graphicLayer.remove(toBeRemoved);
};

var idsToDelete = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

idsToDelete.forEach(function(id) {
  //using map.graphics layer for instance
  removeGraphicById(map.graphics, "id", id);
});
```